# configure iisnode to send all requests to a single js file

Tags: node.js, iisnode

When I add the iisnode HttpModule, I can specify a wildcard for paths that it will handle.  It then expects to find a js file at that path to run.  Instead, is it possible to have all matching requests handled by a single JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Using URL rewriting with node.js applications hosted in IIS using iisnode](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/using-url-rewriting-with-nodejs.html) for an answer.

In short, you can use [IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to redirect all or a subset of the URL space owned by the web site to the file containing your node.js application.